# JavaScript jq scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

It's simple validation module. Now, i can't understand why my functions (validateEmail) can't call successful. I have no js errors, but browser do postback with my form thorought validation code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Validation;
(function (Validation) {
    var FormValidator = (function () {
        function FormValidator(formid) {
            this.emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
            this.formID = formid;
        }
        FormValidator.prototype.Validate = function () {
            var errorsSum;
            $('#' + this.formID).find('input[type="text"][validate], textarea[validate]').each(function (index, item) {
                var validateType = $(item).attr('validate');
                switch(validateType) {
                    case 'text':
                    case 'password': {
                        errorsSum += FormValidator.prototype.validateText(item);
                        break;

                    }
                    case 'email': {
                        errorsSum += FormValidator.prototype.validateEmail(item);
                        break;

                    }
                }
            });
            return errorsSum == 0;
        };
        FormValidator.prototype.validateGeneric = function (element, validationFunc) {
            var jqElement = $(element);
            alert('tested element = ' + jqElement);
            if(validationFunc(jqElement.val())) {
                alert('tested element error = ' + jqElement.val());
                element.removeClass('error');
                return 0;
            } else {
                element.addClass('error');
            }
            alert('tested element success = ' + jqElement.val());
            return 1;
        };
        FormValidator.prototype.validateEmail = function (element) {
            return FormValidator.prototype.validateGeneric(element, function (elementValue) {
                return FormValidator.prototype.emailPattern.test(elementValue);
            });
        };
        FormValidator.prototype.validateText = function (element) {
            return FormValidator.prototype.validateGeneric(element, function (elementValue) {
                return elementValue != '';
            });
        };
        return FormValidator;
    })();
    Validation.FormValidator = FormValidator;    
})(Validation || (Validation = {}));
</script>
```

This is my form

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "register-form", @class = "form-horizontal"}))
    {
        ...    
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @placeholder = @L("Email"), @name = "email", @validate = "email" })
        ...
    }
```

This is validation code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#register-form').submit(function() {
            return (new Validation.FormValidator('register-form').Validate());
        });
    });
</script>
```

I don't understand js so deep

Comment: you should always post the HTML generated by razor/php/etc, not the HTML-generating code itself. it is irrelevant and not helpful.

Comment: Well, what do you mean that you can't call `validateEmail`? Can you elaborate? **edit** You can reference the current instance of FormValidator before the `.each` call, something like `var self = this;` and then from within the `.each` just use `self.validateEmail(item)` instead of `FormValidator.prototype.validateEmail`. Might not fix the issue but then again if you can clarify for me I might be to help better.

Comment: if(validationFunc(jqElement.val())) not returning result... and browser ignore all code after this call

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the submit event and prevent it from firing, validate the form, then submit if it was valid. Right now you are running the javascript as soon as it's submitted, but it just keeps submitting anyway since you don't stop the http request from being made.

On a related note, this is a huge mess. You don't need anything close to that much code just to validate emails and text presence on your form. This is [all you need](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it):

```
var validate = function(form){
  var form_valid = true;

  form.find('input[validate], textarea').each(function(index, el){
    var type = el.attr('validate');

    if (type == 'email') {
      if (!el.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/)) { form_valid = false; el.addClass('error'); }
    }

    if (type == 'text') {
      if (!el.val() == '') { form_valid = false; el.addClass('error'); }
    }
  });

  return form_valid
}

$('#register-form').on('submit', function(){
  validate($(this)) && $(this).submit()
});
```

Hope this helps...

*Edit: made the example a bit more modular*

Comment: His code doesn't just validate the email on the form, it's a validator that will accept different types of inputs to validate.

Comment: Fair enough, modified the example. Still doesn't need anywhere near that much code.

Comment: yes, i know, but i'am using Typescript for create my validation module

Comment: @ZOXEXIVO If you're using TypeScript it might also be good (in addition to providing the generated HTML source not the template language) to supply the TypeScript source. You had your question labeled TypeScript but I did not see any.

Comment: function if(validationFunc(jqElement.val())) craches all time, and i can't understand - whyy ?

Comment: It's best to debug the source rather than the compiled output. You should have attached the typescript source here if you wanted a good answer to this question, as izuriel said.

On the other hand, I don't think you need typescript for something small like this - all it's doing is generating messy and confusing javascript.

Comment: I looked through the code and followed it for a while to track down your issue, but the code is so absurd and convoluted that it was at the point where I'd say this doesn't need a bug fix, it needs a refactor.